# 1 Pixel Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pixel

I have a view in my storyboard that is 1 pixel height.  I have this code to keep it one pixel on every screen.

```
self.onePixelViewHeightConstraintlow.constant = 1.f/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

So it will always stay 1 pixel.  I have a constraint on the view as well, that keeps it 1 pixel height.

Then i added a button, and when the button is pressed the view will  move up.  But when it moves up, i see that sometimes it will become 2 pixels.  Why is that? How can i fix it?

My code, for the button to move the view is.

```
-(void)diabutton:(id)sender{
CGRect frame = self.myObject.frame;
frame.origin.y += 1; //however many pixels to the right..
self.onepixel.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: I am testing the project on my iphone 6 plus as well...

Comment: it works and looks good in the simulator, but not on the iphone 6 plus.   Is the iphone 6 plus, not good enough to do this?

Comment: `frame.origin.y += 1` changes the button origin by 1 *point*, not 1 *pixel*.

Comment: how should i change it by one pixel? Do "1.f"?

Comment: The same way you set `self.onePixelViewHeightConstraintlow.constant`

Comment: Like:     CGRect frame = self.myObject.frame;
          frame.origin.y += 0.5f; //however many pixels to the right..
        self.onePixelViewHeightConstraintlow.constant;

Comment: i get an error when i do that.

Comment: No. Use frame.origin.y += 1.f/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

Comment: I'm still seeing more then 1 line of pixel under a microscope.  Sometimes it will be one, but then when i hit the button to move them, sometimes it will turn into 2 lines.